# Error with h2oEnsemble package installation for R

Tags: r, git, devtools, h2o

I'm trying to install h2oEnsemble package on R 3.2.3. I have H2O 3.10.0.8 package. When I write these commands:

`library(devtools) 
install_github("h2oai/h2o-3/h2o-r/ensemble/h2oEnsemble-package")`

I get the next error:

`Downloading GitHub repo h2oai/h2o-3@master
from URL https://api.github.com/repos/h2oai/h2o-3/zipball/master
Installing h2oEnsemble
"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save  \
  --no-restore --quiet CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpi0Q2AV/devtools9583548338a/h2oai-h2o-3-a0a4bbc/h2o-r/ensemble/h2oEnsemble-package"  \
  --library="C:/Users/User/Documents/R/win-library/3.2" --install-tests 
"C:\Program" ­Ҝ пү«пҜвбп ү­гваҜ­­Ҝ© Ё«Ё ү­Ҝи­Ҝ©
Ө®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбÜ®«­пҜ¬®© Üа®Ҹа ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ü ӨҜв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
Error: Command failed (1)`

Please, help me to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need the latest version, you can use the [CRAN release](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/h2o/index.html)

Comment: just use: `install.packages("https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-ensemble/R/h2oEnsemble_0.1.8.tar.gz", repos = NULL)`

Comment: @phiver : The above code, OP has used is also correct. I tried the same and worked fine. The issue occurs due to space char probably

Comment: @Nishu Tayal, I have no problems with both options on a win7 and win10 machine.

Comment: @phiver: so do I, both options work for me as well :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, your error is :

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. Error: Command failed (1)

It happens due to the space character in location path **(C:\Program Files)** path. According to the documentation,

```
If you want to be able to build packages from sources, we recommend that you choose an 
installation path not containing spaces.
```

Please refer the link : [How do I install R for Windows?](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/rw-FAQ.html#How-do-I-install-R-for-Windows_003f)

Try changing the installation location. Then it should work fine.

Comment: Everything works after installation in a new folder. Thank you